# Unable to show response message from node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am creating `MERN` stack app and trying to save data in database.After data added successfully in database I am sending success message from node server and I want to show this message on front-end side but it is  showing nothing though I am sending message from server.
Below is my code:

React code **form.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import swal from 'sweetalert';

class Form extends Component{

   constructor(props){
     super(props)

       this.state = {

         title:'',
         detail:''
      }
     }

     onTitleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            title:e.target.value
        });
    }

     onDetailChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        detail:e.target.value
      });
    }

     handleSubmit = (e) => {

      e.preventDefault();

          Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/save',{

          title:this.state.title,
          detail:this.state.detail

        }).then((msg) =>{

            swal(msg);

        }).catch((err) => {

             console.log("React Error:",err);            
        });

      } 


  render(){
      return(
          <div className="container">

            <h2 id="formTitle">Add blog</h2>

            <form>

              <div>
                <input type="text" className="validate" name="title" value={this.state.title} placeholder="Title" onChange={this.onTitleChange} required/>
              </div>

               <div>
                  <textarea type="text" value={this.state.detail} className="validate materialize-textarea" name="detail" placeholder="Detail" onChange={this.onDetailChange} required></textarea>
               </div>

              <a href ="/" id="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="waves-effect waves-light btn">SUBMIT</a>

            </form>

          </div>
       )
    }
};

export default Form;
```

**saveData.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const blogs = require('../models/blogPost');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

const dburl = 'mongodb+srv://exp@cluster1-5ws.mongodb.net/expdb?retryWrites=true'

router.post('/save',(req,res) => {

   const data = {

       title: req.body.title,
       detail: req.body.detail
     }

     const newBlog = new blogs(data);

     mongoose.connect(dburl, {useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology:true}).then((resp) =>{

            newBlog.save().then(() => {

                res.json({msg:"Data inserted"});
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log("Insertion error", err);
            });

        }).catch((err) => { 
            console.log("database error: ",err);
        });

});

module.exports = router;
```

mongoose database schema **blogPost.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BlogPostSchema = new Schema({

  title:String,
  detail:String,
  date:{
      type:String,
      dafault:Date.now()
    }
});

const BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost',BlogPostSchema);

module.exports = BlogPost;
```

Someone please let me know what I m doing wrong any help would be appreciated.

**Thanks**

Comment: Whether you are getting response from server??

Comment: First try to print the msg object in console, if u receive it then try a simple browser alert to find out if issue is with swal

Comment: In console when I log response it is sending `msg` object after adding data.

Comment: I have added something like this `then((msg) =>{

                swal(`${msg}`);

            })`   but it is showing  `[Object object]` in alert.

Comment: Problem has been resolved.Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Axios `then` block Simply add `res.data` to get response from server.

```
  Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/save',{

      title:this.state.title,
      detail:this.state.detail

    }).then((res) =>{

        swal(res.data);

    }).catch((err) => {

         console.log("React Error:",err);            
    });
```

**THANKS**